# my authorization app returns false even though I entered the data correctly

Tags: laravel, postgresql, authorization, laravel-passport, laravel-10

I am using laravel passport. it supposed to check whether it matches by comparing the email and password data received from the user via html with the email and password data I saved in the database before. but even if the user data from html is TRUE, the algorithm returns the result as false. I have already confirmed that the hashing algorithm of user input passwords is the same as the hashing algorithms I used when saving them to the database. so what's the problem? why it returns false no matter what? :,)

I checked if both sides hash passwords the same way. If the encryption paths are different, it may be returning false because the hashpasswords do not match, even if the plainpasswords match. But both were encrypted in the same way(at least i guess). I checked also if it is getting the data from the html correctly. it was getting the email and password data entered by the user correctly. I also checked if I'm using the passport's auth:Api function correctly. It supposed to be return true and redirect user to dashboard or whatever but it never returned true even once...

here my authcontroller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class AuthController extends Controller{
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // User login successful
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $request->user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
}     else {
        // User login failed
        return back()->with('error', 'Giriş başarısız.     Lütfen bilgilerinizi kontrol edin.');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your question needs more details, please mind adding some code, read this guide on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: a common mistake I see, is hashing the password twice, so check for that maybe? or provide more details